# Как запросить у пользователя повышение прав?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qfiledialog, getopenfilename

Есть код:

```
directoryfolder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")

with open(directoryfolder,"w") as file:
    file.write("Текст")
```

Когда выполняется строка: `with open(directoryfolder,"w") as file:`
Выходит ошибка:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/make'

Предполагаю, что это из-за недостатка прав пользователя как запросить права администратора?

*UPD*: извиняюсь привел не правильную строчку с выбором папки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script

Comment: Вообще-то правильней будет просто не писать в защищенные каталоги. Корневой каталог системного диска не предназначен для использования приложениями, потому и требуются права администратора. Вам что, действительно абсолютно необходимо туда писать?

Comment: не важно куда писать мне просто не хочет писать даже на рабочий стол. Ошибка все еще актуальна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)` - возвращает кортеж `<class 'tuple'>`

Правильно будет так:
`fileName, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(...)`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit,
            QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QStyle)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):      
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_FileDialogInfoView), 
                           'Open', self)
        self.plainTextEdit.addAction(openFile)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Открыть новый файл')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)  


    def showDialog(self):
        fileName, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                            "Выберите Файл",
                            ".",
                            "Text Files (*.txt *.py)")
        if fileName:
            self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<p style='font:20px;'>
                                           <b style='color:green;'>fileName-> </b>`{}` </p>
                                     <br>
                                     <p style='font:24px;'>
                                       <b style='color:red;'>filetype-> </b>`{}`</p>"""
                                     "".format(fileName, filetype))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.setWindowTitle('File dialog')
    ex.setGeometry(400, 100, 700, 300)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напортачил с первой строчкой где выбирается путь там папка, а не файл не могли бы вы пересмотреть?

Comment: @babaykalopay пересмотреть что?  Смотрите http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName .  `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName` - Это удобная статическая функция, которая возвращает существующий файл, выбранный пользователем. Если пользователь нажимает `Cancel`, он возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: Просто вставьте после `directoryfolder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выберите папку")` строку `print(directoryfolder)` и вам все станет ясно, куда вы пытаетесь записать строку `Текст`